# How to install mongodb on archlinux?

Tags: arch-linux, mongodb

It seems `mongodb` has been removed from the official archlinux repository and it seems compiling is out of the question since I need it on a raspberry pi ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MongoDB)). Where could I find a safe binary of mongodb for archlinux?

(Interestingly, mongodb-tools is still available, although this doesn't make much sense without the db itself ...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well as the `mongodb` package in the AUR, there's also [mongodb34-bin](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mongodb34-bin/), which extracts from the official binary package for 3.4. This should be safe as long as the PKGBUILD looks sane, as it just uses MongoDB's own prebuilt binary (note: you will likely have to modify this to get their official ARM binaries if they exist, this one is likely for x86).

As an alternative, you can cross compile for ARM on x86 with something like [arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc/) instead of compiling directly on the Raspberry Pi, potentially allowing you to use a less resource-constrained environment for compiling (of course, if you have a fast ARM machine you're more than welcome to use that directly, but it seems less likely).